# Dokku deployment not working. Issue with SSH key

Tags: dokku

Here the error

```
fatal: 'fixcodes' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have lost my public key, so I had to create a new one:

1. copy id_rsa.pub to dokku server

Add key:

```
root@localhost:/home/rapsli# dokku ssh-keys:add admin id_rsa.pub
SHA256:FBByHoCiZZzV2xDHmY7RvFhXcTXY0/Bvt1zPJJydmjw
```

creating a new application

```
root@localhost:/home/rapsli# dokku apps:create fixcodes
-----> Creating fixcodes... done
```

Then on my local machine add the remote repo:

```
git remote add dokku dokku@apps.example.com:fixcodes
```

trying to push to it fails.

```
(fixcodes-_8Vg9MY6) λ git push dokku master
fatal: 'fixcodes' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is strange, I can login to the server machine just fine without password:

```
ssh dokku@apps.example.com
```

This works just fine, telling me that the keys are in place. Any ideas?

Comment: Git remotes typically end with `.git` so check it. 
Probably `git remote add dokku dokku@apps.example.com:fixcodes.git` or so.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. Plus in the dokku example they never use the ending .git

Comment: Figures just out: It's not an authentication issue. I can push just fine to existing applications, but when I add a new application I can't push to that one.

Comment: [Zicrou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13317336) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64944857) saying "Have you set a password on the host server?". I expect that was a rhetorical question.